# how to plot wind rose in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have generated a wind rose in Matlab using following MAT-file:

[Wind rose (MatLab Central File Exchange)](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17748-wind-rose)

Its in colors, I don't want colors in my Wind Rose, how do I proceed?
Below is my code which handles the colours and subdivision.

```
[HANDLES,DATA] = wind_rose(DirectionData, SpeedData, 'dtype','meteo', 'di',
    subdivision, 'colors', {[1 0 1] [1 0 1] [1 0 1] [1 0 1] [1 0 1]});
out = gcf;
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the description you would need to replace the part where you indicate which colors you want.

Probably something like so:

```
[HANDLES,DATA] = wind_rose(DirectionData,SpeedData,'dtype','meteo','di',subdivision,'cmap',colormap(bone)); out = gcf;
```

Just tried and `colormap(bone)` will give you a grayscale image.

---

### Example:

```
 d=0:10:350;
 D=[];
 V=[];
 for i=1:length(d)
   n=d(i)/10;
   D=[D ones(1,n)*d(i)];
   V=[V 1:n];
 end

 wind_rose(D,V,'cmap',colormap(bone))
```

Comment: @fredd I see, you actually need inputs like these: `'cmap',colormap(bone)` (only the name of the colormap was not sufficient). Have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for taking the time to reply.

yeah its a good idea to use the above code, though I implemented by changing the colors manually... such as

> [HANDLES,DATA] = wind_rose(Data, Y data,subdivision,'colors',{[0.9 0.9 0.9] [0.8 0.8 0.8] [0.5 0.5 0.5] [0.31 0.31 0.31] [0 0 0] });

By this way, I was able to control my grey scale to my taste..